# How do I convert a Linux-powered laptop into a network-agnostic wireless hard drive?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I have 4 TB of data which I would like to access from all of my devices. It currently resides on a Linux-powered Toughbook 31. My other devices include an Intel NUC (Linux, 512 GB), a smartphone (Android, 32 GB), and a tablet (Windows, 128 GB).

The short version is that I would like to setup a server which allows my devices to mount the laptop, as if it was a network drive, and have read/write access to its files. The laptop must not require being tethered to the same network; if I travel, and the network changes, I should be able to connect the laptop and mobile devices, and they can access the data.

Essentially... I want to turn my laptop into a wireless hard drive which maintains its usability as a laptop. Is this possible? For example... is there a file-sharing mechanism or app which can operate between these three operating systems? Can Nextcloud be run on the laptop and configured in a manner that it can "jump" between networks without needing to change the login IP address on each device?

How do I do this?

Edit. The reason I would like to "take my cloud with me" and not leave it at home is the bandwidth: 100 Kbps up, 5 Mbps down. In my area, no one can give me anything better.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a VPN is for. Pop each device into the VPN and you can share data between each device. Try [Algo](https://github.com/trailofbits/algo) for rolling your own VPN in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single solution to this problem, and indeed I am doubtful this can be deployed reliably.

The first option would be to deploy a VPN server (like openVPN) at a location which is always reachable, then have your home network connect to it, as well as your laptop and other devices.   Running SAMBA on your laptop and pointing your other devices as the IP address the VPN assigns your laptop will allow you to read and write files, albeit with slow speeds - and indeed one of the big drawbacks of this solution is the inefficiency of using VPN architecture - which compounds the problem of a floating laptop.

Using Nextcloud requires a Nexcloud server, and then synchronises everything with that.  Its a nice technical solution but does not leave the source of truth on your laptop, and requires a disk "in the cloud" or on a static network.  This is a sustainable model if disk is cheap.

The solution which I deployed was to add aa fileserver on my LAN, and a VPN terminating on my LAN so I can access the data on the fileserver remotely and seurely.   The fileserver runs SAMBA, NFS and a DLNA server so it can feed my TV and other media devices, My wifes Windows systems, and my Linux systems.  The downside is that to reach this I need a static IP address (which I need anyway), or otherwise I could hack it with DynamicDNS - but you will also need to fiddle with the router (I use a router with DD-WRT)

Comment: I added an edit: my home bandwidth is 100/5,000 kbps up/down.